# How to search every word separated by comma in textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have text box ...If i type in textbox like

"C,C++,ASP.net,4-5Years"  then every word should be checked by database whether that name exits or not in table field of the database. It should be check separately of every word, just like Search engines.

How can i do in asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly quick-and-dirty but will get you started.

```
string[] split = YourTextBox.Text.Split(new char[] {','});
foreach(string str in split)
{
    //check the database about str
    //perhaps using a LIKE query for partial matches
}
```

Comment: Ya Its Working perfectly...But i have small issues..

when i enter in text box like c,c++,4-5 yrs
it have to check in database like
either c,c++ skills and 4-5 yrs experiecne and then the reult has to be shown...
Burt as per ur query it just show results whether any one of keyword satisfy database ...I want to compare year also how?